# I have a huge dataset of machine position data in MongoDB and I am using node js. I want to query hourly values (for every single hour)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

The data looks like this. I need to calculate the distance travelled by a user. I achieved that and can specify a date range and it shows the result. But now I need to calculate the hourly values. Every single hour by a user.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576"),
    "Date" : ISODate("2016-06-16T09:54:29.379Z"),
    "MessageType" : "GPGGA",
    "Location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            11.20, 
            48.83
        ]
    },
    "Quality" : "Rtk",
    "TimeSinceLastDgpsUpdate" : "09:57:27.2000000",
    "Username" : "xyz"
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far, i.e. how to you calculate the distance travelled.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's very impressive what you have done. The code looks very good, I specified date range because the data is very huge. After running it doesn't show anything, it is taking ages to run. If I run the same on Mongo playground as you said, it runs there. I am trying to run it, I am using visual studio code and connected my database through that.

Comment: Do you have an index on `Date`? If you like to calculate only a specific date range then such index should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const geo = require('geojson-tools');  // package required to calculate the distance
// fetching the collection from MongoDB database
    const collectionResult = db.collection.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
              Date: {
                // mention the date range from and until
                $gte: new Date("2019-06-25T09:49:32.398Z"),  
                $lt: new Date("2019-06-28T09:54:29.379Z")
              }
            }
          },    
          { $addFields: { DateParts: { $dateToParts: { date: "$Date" } } } },
          // Create hourly value 
          {
             $addFields: {
                Date_Hour: {
                   $dateFromParts: {
                      year: "$DateParts.year",
                      month: "$DateParts.month",
                      day: "$DateParts.day",
                      hour: "$DateParts.hour"
                   }
                }
             }
          },
          // Sort documents in order to get proper track
          { $sort: { Username: 1, Date: 1 } },
          // Group by user and hour
          {
            $group: {
              _id: {username: "$Username", date_hour: "$Date_Hour"},
              items: {
                $push: {
                  locations: "$Location"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          // Sort documents in order to get proper track
          { $sort: {username: 1, date_hour: 1 } }
       ])
       // save the collection results to array for calculating the distance 
       const distanceResults = collectionResult.toArray(function (err, result) {
          if (err) throw err;

          const distances = result.map((item) => {
            // console.info(item._id.username)
            const coordinates = item.items.map(x => x.locations).map(x => x.coordinates)
            const distance = {
              username: item._id.username,
              date: item._id.date_hour,
              distance: geo.getDistance(coordinates, 4)
            }
            console.info(JSON.stringify(distance))
            return distance
          })

          db.close();
          return distances
        })
        return distanceResults
      }) 
    }
```

It shows the perfect result I think and using the geojson package it is very easy to calculate the distance.

Thank you so much for your help.

The answer is like this

```
{"username":"ABC","date":"2019-06-25T12:00:00.000Z","distance":1.5888}
{"username":"CDE","date":"2019-06-25T15:00:00.000Z","distance":0.188}
{"username":"FGH","date":"2019-06-27T06:00:00.000Z","distance":12.041}
{"username":"IJK","date":"2019-06-27T09:00:00.000Z","distance":1.5506}
{"username":"LMN","date":"2019-06-28T08:00:00.000Z","distance":0.0206}
```

Answer (score 0):

First generate hourly values of Date. Then calculate distances for these hour and user.

```
function haversine() {
   var radians = Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function (deg) { return deg / 180.0 * Math.PI; });
   var lat1 = radians[0], lon1 = radians[1], lat2 = radians[2], lon2 = radians[3];
   if (!lat1 || !lon1)
      return 0;
   var R = 6372.8 * 1000; // meters
   var dLat = lat2 - lat1;
   var dLon = lon2 - lon1;
   var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
   var c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
   return R * c;
}

var preLon, preLat, preUser, preHour

db.collection.aggregate([
   { $addFields: { DateParts: { $dateToParts: { date: "$Date" } } } },
   {
      $addFields: {
         Date_Hour: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: "$DateParts.year",
               month: "$DateParts.month",
               day: "$DateParts.day",
               hour: "$DateParts.hour"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $sort: { Username: 1, Date: 1 } }
]).forEach(function (doc) {
   if ( preUser != doc.Username || preHour != doc.Date_Hour.getTime() ) {
      // maybe other conditions for reset should be added
      preLon = null;
      preLat = null;
      preUser = null;
      preHour = null;      
   }
   distance = haversine(preLat, preLon, doc.Location.coordinates[1], doc.Location.coordinates[0])
   preLon = doc.Location.coordinates[0];
   preLat = doc.Location.coordinates[1];
   preUser = doc.Username;
   preHour = doc.Date_Hour.getTime();
   db.collection.updateOne(
      { _id: doc._id },
      { $set: { distance: distance, Date_Hour: doc.Date_Hour } }
   )
})
```

Afterwards you can 
sum the distances by user and hour:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { Username: "$Username", hour: "$Date_Hour" },
         distance: { $sum: "$distance" }
      }
   },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$_id"] } } },
   { $unset: "_id" }
])
```

Sample result:

```
{ 
    "distance" : 111226.34257109408, 
    "Username" : "abc", 
    "hour" : ISODate("2016-06-16T21:00:00.000+0200")
}
{ 
    "distance" : 111226.34257109408, 
    "Username" : "abc", 
    "hour" : ISODate("2016-06-16T11:00:00.000+0200")
}
{ 
    "distance" : 8108.472378934691, 
    "Username" : "xyz", 
    "hour" : ISODate("2016-06-16T11:00:00.000+0200")
}
```

Another approach (without JavaScript function) would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $addFields: { DateParts: { $dateToParts: { date: "$Date" } } } },
   // Create hourly value 
   {
      $addFields: {
         Date_Hour: {
            $dateFromParts: {
               year: "$DateParts.year",
               month: "$DateParts.month",
               day: "$DateParts.day",
               hour: "$DateParts.hour"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Sort documents in order to get proper track
   { $sort: { Username: 1, Date: 1 } },
   // Group by user and hour
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {Username: "$Username", Date_Hour: "$Date_Hour"},
         Locations: { $push: "$Location" }
      }
   },
   // Put "Location" & "Location+1" into array in order to get a line
   {
      $addFields: {
         distance: {
            $map: {
               input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$Locations" }] },
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: { $eq: ["$$this", 0] },
                     then: null,
                     else: [
                        { $arrayElemAt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$Locations.coordinates", { $subtract: ["$$this", 1] }] }, 0] },
                        { $arrayElemAt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$Locations.coordinates", { $subtract: ["$$this", 1] }] }, 1] },
                        { $arrayElemAt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$Locations.coordinates", "$$this"] }, 0] },
                        { $arrayElemAt: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$Locations.coordinates", "$$this"] }, 1] }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Calculate the haversine 
   {
      $set: {
         distance: {
            $map: {
               input: "$distance",
               in: {
                  $let: {
                     vars: {
                        dlon: { $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 0] }, { $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 2] }] } },
                        dlat: { $degreesToRadians: { $subtract: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 1] }, { $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 3] }] } },
                        lat1: { $degreesToRadians: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 1] } },
                        lat2: { $degreesToRadians: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$this", 3] } }
                     },
                     in: {
                        // sin²(dLat / 2) + sin²(dLon / 2) * cos(lat1) * cos(lat2);
                        $add: [
                           { $pow: [{ $sin: { $divide: ["$$dlat", 2] } }, 2] },
                           { $multiply: [{ $pow: [{ $sin: { $divide: ["$$dlon", 2] } }, 2] }, { $cos: "$$lat1" }, { $cos: "$$lat2" }] }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Calculate the distance (in meters, given by "6372.8 * 1000")
   {
      $set: {
         distance: {
            $map: {
               input: "$distance",
               in: { $multiply: [6372.8, 1000, 2, { $asin: { $sqrt: "$$this" } }] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Sum up distance parts
   { $set: { distance: { $sum: "$distance" } } },
   // Remove unused fields
   { $unset: "Locations" }
])
```

See [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1PkXwGou5di)

You may have a look at [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/index.html). This provide the distance automatically by `distanceField`. However, you cannot specify a rectangle (i.e. `$box`) as filter, you must specify a point plus `maxDistance`.

Comment: Dear Wernfried, Thank you so much, I will try this and will get back to you. I hope it will work, its been like a week, I couldn't find any solution. I will check this. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RahulBhat, see also my hint for `$geoNear`

Comment: I think GeoNear won't work in my case, the one you have specified looks great. I am trying to figure out how to resolve the issue by using your code first. I will get back to if I find something or if I resolve it. Have a nice weekend. Cheers

Comment: hey Hi @Wernfried, I ran the second one without javascript and I am getting this error: "distance is not defined" but I used some other way and it worked but I am not sure it's showing the right results i.e per hour ```